# which tool use to create Perl executable

Tags: perl, pp-perl-par-packager, perlapp, perl2exe

I want to create Perl script executable exe for distributions for enterprise use.
For security and to stop misuse.
I found many outdated post about it. But today I don't know it is similar or not!

Question is:
Which tool shall I use to create executables?

I used previously following:

PAR::Packer - Most favorite choice of mine. But its just packer. Source code can be extracted using any extraction tool like 7zip, winzip.

perl2exe - provides some sort of encryption. But painful sometimes

PerlApp - comes with PDK

perlcc - Its outdated

Comment: Nothing has changed.  All current packaging solutions are reversible.  Of course anything you give out can be reverse engineered.

Comment: @tjd do you know how to extract code from perl2exe?

Comment: I just searched Google for "perl2exe" and there's a lovely tutorial sitting right on the 1st page.  Bonus:  Now you too know!

Comment: @tjd those posts are outdated. I already tried for it.

Answer (score 2):

If security is your main concern, run the code on a server as a service. Write a client to connect to the service (might be a web client) and distribute it to users. Or switch to a compiled language.

Comment: My code is going to be a part of the software(GUI based). To run the code on server is good option. But not applicable for my problem.